SharePoint List Validation Formula
I am trying to build out a SharePoint List validation formula. I can get the first part to work but when I try to add the second part, it will not work for either. I have tried multiple if/and/or combinations and need help.
Working Code:
=IF([Accrual Amount]<>"",IF([Color]<>"GREEN",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
Code to add:
=IF([Accrual Amount]="",IF([Color]="GREEN",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
The goal is that if either of those scenarios are True, it will give an error message telling the user they need to fix the field.
Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated!!!

What is the column/data type of "Accrual Amount"?

Try using this formula for your SharePoint list validation settings:
=IF([Accrual Amount]="",IF([Color]="GREEN",FALSE,TRUE),IF([Color]<>"GREEN",FALSE,TRUE))

You can also try this and see which one works for you:
=IF(ISBLANK([Accrual Amount]),IF([Color]="GREEN",FALSE,TRUE),IF([Color]<>"GREEN",FALSE,TRUE))

Follow my answers given in below threads to add formula in List validation settings:

List validation to make multiple fields mandatory if dropdown meets condition
How to have validation for calculated column

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].


Ganesh, thank you for you response. One of the formulas assumes that Accrual Amount (currency) is populated and the other assumes that the field is blank so your formulas don't quite work. Any ideas on combining the two different scenarios I posted above?
